# Need an good introductory tutorials on TFS build process

Tags: tfs, build-process

We are slowly rolling out team foundation, and I have to get up to speed on setting up a Build process on TFS.

What are some good starting points TFS builds?

From what it seems, there is no GUI for TFS build right?  It is just about learning MSBuild?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Team Build in 2008 is completely revamped from what was provided in 2005.  I am assuming that you are talking about 2008, since it is the more current version.

A great place to start is over at Buck Hodge's blog.  Buck is the team lead for Team Build.  Specifically, he has an article called [TFS 2008: A basic guide to Team Build 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/08/14/tfs-2008-a-basic-guide-to-team-build-2008.aspx) which is a great starting point.

Also, as a person working on a team migrating to Team Foundation Server, I highly recommend training with a Microsoft-endorsed training provider.  We went with [Notion Solutions](http://www.notionsolutions.com/Pages/default.aspx).  It is inexpensive and fairly reasonable quality.  It is self-paced video training with hosted labs, and instructor question and answer time available, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Joseph's [pointers](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/08/14/tfs-2008-a-basic-guide-to-team-build-2008.aspx) the following talk I gave includes the majority of the slides from a session I did with Brian Randall on Team Foundation Build at TechEd EMEA in 2007.

http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/team_foundation_4.html

In TFS2008 and earlier, Team Build is very heavily based on MSBuild.  For a quick intruction to MSBuild read Chapter 5 of the book [Deploying .NET Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596528).  The chapter is available free online here:

http://en.csharp-online.net/MSBuild:_By_Example

Hope that helps,

Martin.

Comment: Nice slide deck, Martin.  Definitely will share with my team!

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at this book: http://blogs.msdn.com/microsoft_press/archive/2009/01/31/sayed.aspx